# Can someone explaine why my function handle does not work?

Tags: matlab

Newbe here so please don't be too harsh.
I have these three functions, and each has it's own file:

```
format long
rd = @(x) runden(x,L);
function y = runden(x,L)
    y = (round(x*10^L))/10^L;
endfunction

format long
function z = add(x,y,rd)
  z = rd(rd(x)+rd(y));
endfunction

format long
function z = mult(x,y,rd)
  z = rd(rd(x)*rd(y));
endfunction
```

as you see I want to use a function handle, so I can use round in the bottom two functions.
The functions have to be in their own files (wasn't a problem so far in matlab).
My Syntax is off, but I can't find a tutorial that handles function handles with two variables.

Comment: What value do you want to give `L`? Why are you using function handles rather than calling the `runden` function directly?

Comment: What error, if any, are you getting?

Comment: L is the position I want to round at. for example I get the long: 0.1212 and L is 3 so the result should be 0.121.

Comment: >> add(10,2)
error: 'rd' undefined near line 4 column 10
error: called from
    add at line 4 column 5
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
error: called from
    add at line 4 column 5

Comment: _I have these three functions, and each has its own file_ You have _four_ functions, one of them anonymous (with function handle `rd`). How are they organized into files exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, the function handle `rd` lives only in the first script, and the other scripts can't access it.
If you will name the first file (function) as `runden.m`, and define `rd` in the other functions and not in the first one, they will have access to it.

And two notes- don't override preserved function names as `add`, and use `end` instead of `endfunction`.

I would suggest to arrange the functions like that:

```
% file 1, named `runden.m`
function y = runden(x,L)
  format long
  y = (round(x*10^L))/10^L;
end

% file 2, named `ad.m`
function z = ad(x,y,L)
  format long
  rd = @(x) runden(x,L);
  z = rd(rd(x)+rd(y));
end

% file 3, named `mult.m`
function z = mult(x,y,L)
  format long
  rd = @(x) runden(x,L);
  z = rd(rd(x)*rd(y));
end
```

Comment: 1. what's the names of the files? 2. Are they all in the current folder? 3. How did you call the function that you called to?

Comment: BTW, what's the point of `format long` if you not display any number?

Comment: See the edit- you should also pass `L` to the functions, otherwise Matlab doesn't know its value. Works perfect for me.

Comment: the files are named round.m, add.m, and mult.m, and they are all in the same folder. I am using format long so I can use a larger L. I tried setting L = 5, but still got an error that it was not defined.

Comment: @DanielGießing: [`format`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) only affects the *display* format, not the numerical precision. The variable is still a double-precision number.

Comment: @DanielGießing Don't name a file or a function with a reserved word. Try to define and save the functions and files exactly as in the answer, it works fine for me.